# Jump to another "View Controller" with native camera

Tags: ios, swift3, view, camera

I have a doubt as to how to develop a part of my code.
I am creating an App in Swift 3.0 and reached a point, there is a button that will have the native iphone camera.

What I want is:

- When you take a photo and press the "Use Photo" button, jump to 
   another view controller. How can I do it?

  The code that I will have the camera is

  ```
  @IBAction func openInterfaceTakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

      if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
          var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
          imagePicker.delegate = self
          imagePicker.sourceType = .camera;
          imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
          self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
  }
  ```

I have written the following text to detect when we press on UsePhoto and jump to ViewController:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let takedPhotoVC: TakedPhotoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "TakedPhoto", bundle: 
    nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TakedPhotoVC") as! 
    TakedPhotoVC 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(takedPhotoVC, animated: false)}

}
```

**But the terminal shows the following error**: Snapshotting a view that has not 
    been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been ..

- And another doubt, in the Xcode simulator can you open the camera?

Thank you very much

Comment: What actually You want to achieve? Why you want to go to another controller on camera click?

Comment: "And another doubt, in the Xcode simulator can you open the camera" No. In fact, you should not even _mention_ the camera in the simulator.

Comment: I want to capture a photo and when we click on the "Use Photo" button the App will jump to another "View Controller" where it will be divided into two parts, the top part will contain the map showing the location where the photo was taken and the second part, a square, where we can put the description. Thanks :) !

Answer (score 1):

When the user taps the Use Photo button, your image view controller *delegate* is called. It can receive the image, dismiss the image view controller, and go to another view controller.

If that's not enough for you, then you should rethink your approach. You can't easily modify the UIImagePickerController view interface. It is intentionally simple-minded, and it doesn't belong to you. If you want a Use Photo button that you are in control of, you'd be better off designing your own picture-taking interface using AVFoundation.

Comment: I have written the following text to detect when we press on UsePhoto and jump to ViewController:func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {let takedPhotoVC:  TakedPhotoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "TakedPhoto", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TakedPhotoVC") as! TakedPhotoVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(takedPhotoVC, animated: false)} But the terminal shows the following error: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been ...

Comment: Then you should have said that in your question. You can't get good help if you completely conceal your actual code, can you? We're not mind-readers.

Comment: I expressed myself wrong in the previous message. The code I wrote before was thanks to you :). But, I get the error that I tell you "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been ...". What I can do? Thank you.